# SSISDB stop operations keep running indefinitely

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Title says about as much as I can say, I have tried stopping these packages from running but the stop operations seem to have no end. How can I kill the running operations?

I have tried restarting the server but they still seem to be running

[image]

Update:

Here's the activity monitor processes with all the operations still running as above:

[image]

So my solution, which is not really a solution was just to delete the SSISDB and create a new one. If you find a real solution please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Right click `SSISDB` under `Integration Services Catalog` - Select `Active operations` - Select your operation and click stop.

You can also script this to for example

```
USE SSISDB
GO

EXEC [catalog].[stop_operation] 82428
```

You can also get all your running status by doing this:

```
SELECT 'exec [catalog].[stop_operation] ' + CAST(operation_id as varchar(10))
  FROM [SSISDB].[internal].[operations]

  where status = 2
```

And then copy them to a query window and execute it.

And if that doesnt work - You could either stop your SQL Job agent Job or kill the processes under Activity Monitor - But that should be the last option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, your first solution is how I initially tried to stop the operations. If you look at my image you can see I have already tried stopping the operations. The jobs are not in the activity monitor either which I can see. When I run the execute the above `stop operation` I get the error that a stop operations is already running

Comment: @WarricRitchie can you show the error? And can you show the status of activity monitor and the SQL job agent history?

Comment: Otherwise try to update your operation_id in operations table in ssisdb with status  = 4. Update internal.operations set status = 4 where operation_id = your id from active operations

Comment: Error is as follows: **Integration Services server cannot stop the operation. The specified operation is already in Stopping state.** And unfortunately the SQL server agent is not activated on my side, any options here?

Comment: unfortunately updating the table does not  solve the issue as the stop operation is still running and the execution time still increasing

Comment: Can you stop and restart the SQL server agent Service under Services?

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```sql
select * from catalog.executions where status = 2
```

Then, to kill an Active Operation, use this:

```
/* THIS IS A KILL OPERATION*/ 
--USE SSISDB
--GO
--EXEC [catalog].[stop_operation] 1211899
```